# Open the multiple linked only after user confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I am trying to open a multiple links to open a popup/user confirmation window like "are you sure to open the window?" If yes then open a link in new window

```
<li class="footerlink"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link 1</a></li>
<li class="footerlink"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Link 2</a></li>
<li class="footerlink"><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">Link 3 </a></li>
```

Is that possible in JQuery/javascript to handle multiple links?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li class="footerlink"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link 1</a></li>
<li class="footerlink"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Link 2</a></li>
<li class="footerlink"><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">Link 3 </a></li>

 $(".footerlink").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault() // this will prevent from `a` tag to open its href
   var r = confirm("Are you sure??");
   if(r == true){
     var link=document.createElement('a');
         link.href=$(this).find('a').attr("href");
         link.target="_blank";
         link.click();
    }

});
```

Comment: thanks for a reply.. but this function will work on the whole 'a' tag? i just want confirmation window on footer link

Comment: It wont work for the whole tag.. give a specific class name for the footer links, then  you call like `$(".footerClass").click(function(){ // code });

Comment: I don't understand Anoop LL ? :(

Comment: its showing an error "e.preventdefault is not a function" Anoop LL

Comment: its preventDefault()... D capital

Comment: Thanks, its fixed but when i click OK on the popup window the new window appear and showing me Undefined instead of open a link

Comment: mate its still same "Undifined" window

Comment: @user3385695 The issue is that footerlink class is given for li not a.. i have updated code

Comment: Thanks mate its working now i put footerlink class in 'a' tag.just have a quick question... how can i use http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ instead of by default popup up.. the reason because its showing a check-box option prevent this page from creating additional dialogs and i don't want this message

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline javascript if you're looking for a simple confirmation (yes/no) like so:

```
<li class="footerlink"><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="http://www.google.com">Link 1</a></li>
<li class="footerlink"><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Link 2</a></li>
<li class="footerlink"><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">Link 3 </a></li>
```

OR you could write a seperate function for a more complex dialog (bootstrap modals for example). In which case you replace the return confirm('message') with your own custom function:

```
<li class="footerlink"><a onclick="return customConfirm(this)" href="http://www.google.com">Link 1</a></li>
<li class="footerlink"><a onclick="return customConfirm(this)" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Link 2</a></li>
<li class="footerlink"><a onclick="return customConfirm(this)" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">Link 3 </a></li>

function customConfirm(e) {
    // Do your thing!
}
```